# Using a Boolean in an If-Statement in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

I have some code with an if-statement in it, and one of the conditions is a boolean. However, CodeSkulptor says "Line 36: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for BitAnd: 'bool' and 'number'". Please help if you can. This is what that piece of code looks like. (I just changed all the variable names and what the if-statement executes)

```
thing1 = True
thing2 = 3

if thing2 == 3 & thing1:
   print "hi"
```

Comment: Use and instead of &. One word of caution, use parentheses among the expressions that you want to evaluate. You can find unexpected results if you do not.

Comment: @Imagine: `==` has a higher precedence than `and`, so nothing will happen.

Comment: @Blender True, but to quote the zen of python: explicit is better than implicit. I'd rather add unnecessary yet clarifying parentheses than rely on an imperfect knowledge of operator precedence.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart: I've rarely seen `if (foo == 2) and bar`, but it's personal preference to add them in if you feel that they make it clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use logical `and` (not the `&`, which is a bitwise AND operator in Python):

```
if thing2 == 3 and thing1:
   print "hi"
```

Because you have used `&`, the error has popped up, saying:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for BitAnd: 'bool' and 'number'
                                           ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 4):

`&` is the bitwise AND operator. You want to use the logical `and` instead:

```
if thing2 == 3 and thing1:
    print "hi"
```